# Is there a little and beautiful program demonstrate perl OO?

Tags: perl

Is there a little and beautiful program to demonstrate Perl OO, that I can study and follow;
using `bless`, including constructors, destructors, inheritance and almost all OO stuff?

Thanks.

Comment: The perltoot(1) manpage has sufficient snippets for study and demonstration.

Comment: I'm confused after read perlboot,perltoot and perltooc...I need a good real program

Comment: There are hundreds of perl modules out there for you to study, I know of none particularly made for teaching. Maybe you could try asking your questions directly here?

Comment: perlboot, perltoot, perltooc are deleted. Read [perlootut](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/perl-5.15.6/pod/perlootut.pod) ([future permalink](http://p3rl.org/perlootut)) and [perlobj](http://p3rl.org/perlobj) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't *classical* Perl OO, but if you want to use [Moose](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose) then it has good [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose::Manual) and a [cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose::Cookbook) (with lots of examples).

Comment: Definitely use Moose over the built in object system.